# How to transfer content of object of objects into array of objects and order it

Tags: javascript

Given the following object

```
data = {
 "c": {name: "c"},
 "2": {name: "two"},
 "1": {name: "one"},
 "a": {name: "a"}
}
```

It should end in an array with the following order

```
 [
 {name: "a"},
 {name: "c"},
 {name: "one"},
 {name: "two"}
 ]
```

How can I do so?

Because if I do

```
let newArr = []

for (let i in data){newArr.push(data[i])}
```

It ends up as

```
 [ 
 {name: "one"},
 {name: "two"},
 {name: "a"},
 {name: "c"}
 ]
```

Comment: _"with the following order"_ - What's the rule behind that order? Use it in your [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) callback and you're done

Comment: You might also want to have a look at [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) and the methods that are available, e.g. `Object.values()`

Comment: @Andreas its ordering it by "a", "c", "1", "2" . First letters then numbers based on the data object index

Comment: Now translate these rules into JS -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Logic.**

- Sort the keys in your required format. Alphabets first, numbers last.
- Return the data from your array based on this sorted keys.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
const data = {
  "c": { name: "c" },
  "2": { name: "two" },
  "1": { name: "one" },
  "a": { name: "a" }
}
const sortedKeys = Object.keys(data).sort().sort((a, b) => {
  if ((isNaN(a) && isNaN(b)) || (!isNaN(a) && !isNaN(b))) { // Both are same type
    return a < b;
  } else { // a nad b are of different types
    return -1;
  }
});

const output = sortedKeys.map((key) => data[key]);
console.log(output);
```